# PIXI v4 - Is possible to disable Multi Texture Batching in PIXI v4 ?

Tags: javascript, graphics, phaser

I would like to know if is possible to disable the multi texture batching in a PIXI V4 game.

Recently i jus update my game PIXI lib from version 3 to 4.2. I`m using cocoon Canvas + . It seems perfect on iOS and android version greater than 5. 
In a old phone the texture batching is messing with the textures.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6wVYRm731I&feature=youtu.be

Please. Is possible to disable it. 
  
I already tried

```
PIXI["settings"].SPRITE_MAX_TEXTURES = 1;
PIXI["settings"].SPRITE_BATCH_SIZE = 1024;
```

without success